# Best way to replace this Antec server PSU

Tags: hardware, power-supply-unit, replace

The power supply in one of my servers died.
After a few checks it seems it didn't provided enough power to the machine's hard-disks.

A straightforward solution would be a new PSU but I can't find one like it that has the mains power connector *inside* - on the same side where the low voltage cable tree for the mainboard etc. is (see pictures).

[image]

This is the PSU, antec sl300xrp

[image]

This is the server, the room is limited and the PSU needs to be in the right bottom corner

Any suggestions what to do? and if this kind of  PSU is still being made?

Comment: Belongs on serverFault.com, without a doubt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Honestly, you can probably get a great server from ebay or craigslist for less than replacing the power supply.  I know HP Proliant servers best, so briefly:
DL servers are rack-mount; ML are towers.
Like BMW, they have 100, 300, 500, and 700 series (Yes, I know BMW doesn't have a 100 series, but roll with it.)
At the end of that will be a "G" number.  This is the "generation" of the server.  G2's are the second generation; G6's are the sixth generation.  I'd recommend at least a G4.  G6's and G7's are brand new, but price will reflect.

I'd recommend against anything 100-series.  I have the most experience with the DL380, DL580 and DL760.  The 760 will probably be waaaay more machine (and less disk) than you need.  Different configurations of the 300 and 500 series will store different kinds of disk.  G4s will be either Ultra-320 disks or SAS, but G5's and later will usually be SAS.  Ultra-320 disks are widely available cheaply; it is aging tech, but I still would buy them for personal or small business use.

Just be sure to get the dual power supplies, and read up on using iLO (Integrated Lights-Out - it's a built in VNC server and virtual power button, among other things.)  It's fantastic and will change your life.

Comment: We're still running 4 360G4s and 3 360G3s. They have been rock solid. As @gWaldo said they are on the old side thus why we are moving to new equipment. They do not support the newer xeon chips w/ VT, so no virtualization.

Comment: Good point, Thoreau.  G5s (certain ones, at least) are the first to support VT.  You can run virtualization on earlier platforms, but they're certainly not optimized!  360's are good too, but since it seems that disk quantity was a factor, I recommend at least 2U servers.

Answer (score 1):

Antec appears to have a global network of resellers and distributors have a look [**here**](http://www.antec.com/Believe_it/?page=wheretobuy). They also have a global support system that you can contact [**here**](http://www.antec.com/Believe_it/index.php?page=support_online).

Comment: Antec Told us they didnt had support for this model anyone and there are no new models with this setup, tried that

Comment: This is why you buy a server from a large vendor and keep up on your warranty...

Answer (score 1):

[Iain has the right idea](https://serverfault.com/questions/175214#175220), but it might be cheaper to buy a whole new case than just one ancient power supply; just a thought.

Comment: I think a whole new case is a bit overrated.
Currently checking if we can build in a smaller supply  with at least 300W
other posibility im checking is the buy a normal one and have an electician change the sides

Comment: Just buy a new case your electrician will cost more.

Comment: You're probably best off buying a whole new server at this point; at the very least a case, but you're probably just putting a band-aid on the real problem. I understand wanting to be cheap and keep old hardware running; but it's either necessary for the business or it's not (and just just pitch the whole thing).

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar server case with standard PSU. My case has a 90° angled power connector going into the PSU so it fits in the small space between the PSU and the case. You could just buy such a connector and replace your straight one, if it will be enough to fit everything in the case.